# How to create customised tag for javascript? Or is this something else that I don't know?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a multi-language function on wordpress. Each article or page will contain 2 language versions, I need to use a tag to separate them and let my JavaScript knows which section to pull according to the current language option.

I may have something like this in the editor?

```
[english]
English Content
[/english]
[chinese]
中文内容
[/chinese]
```

OK so my question is how to have a function to let javascript to recognise the [] and the text in it? or is this something that can be done in the wordpress API? since I have seen kinds of plugins using this in the article.

Comment: why you don't fill the data in two different divs then according to selection show/hide the div if its a small things for multilang ????

Comment: @raman i wish i can do this since the client will wanna manage this site himself and he doesnt know html...

Comment: i am not getting what you want to say??

Comment: @raman I meant my client will need to manage this website' content by himself but I don't want him to touch the html part, indeed he doesn't know html as well, that's why i came out this question here.

Comment: my sorry for didn't make the question clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you don't create your own tags, but use normal html element with the `lang` attribute:

```
<div lang="en">
   English Content
</div>
<div lang="zh">
   中文内容
</div>
```

This way you can use the standard css and javascript to work with the content, like this:

```css
*[lang=zh]{
   display:none;
}
```

and then you could switch the display via javascript when the chinese language is chosen.

<sup>The universal selector `*` should be avoided if possible and replaced for a more specific selector.</sup>

Alternatively, if you don't want to bother your client with html-stuff, let them write these pseudo-tags `[english] / [chinese]` and convert these after saving into the divs with the according language tags.

Simple regex for capturing the content of such tags (not failproof!):

```
/\[english\](.*?)\[\/english\]/  // -> content will be in first capturegroup
```

Just for fun i coded some tiny example how such a replacement could work:

[Replacement of custom tags into divs with language-id](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/wvJKv/5/)

Comment: thanks..I actually wanted to do this, but my concern is dont want my client to touch the html portion. but it looks there is no other way now, i will go for that, thanks anyway:)

Comment: yea thats what i am thinking, anyway problem solved, thanks man

Comment: @WJ___ i coded something just for fun, perhaps this might help you, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for seeing this late..Come on u really did this for fun? u already done me a whole function for my project..Thanks, man. u Really love scripting huh:) @Christoph

Comment: @WJ___ You are welcome;) Sure I love coding :-D Please be aware that you have to tweak this as currently it does not correctly identify all misplaced tags. (e.g. mixed tags like this: `[english][chinese][/english]`)

Comment: for now it is more than enough:) ur function showed me a good mind map and now i know how to go in already. Looks i have to study hard on Regex lol @Christoph

Answer (score 1):

Here is a RegEx way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/fFzJ4/17/

Too much code to put here :)

Comment: Thanks @Christoph I got ya version

Comment: @WJ___ I added a very simple regex to my answer, perhaps you can use it.